# Does npm install have cascading effect for each dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, node-modules, npm-registry

Let's say I have an app where my package.json has a **library** I am hosting in my own registry(Gitlab for eg.)

And that **library** has some dependencies, so of course, it has package.json of its own.

Now, if I run `npm i` for my app when it reaches my library does it run `npm i` to install dependencies of my library?

Asking because my library has a limit on fetching its dependencies.

Not sure if it makes sense. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll try to be a little more thorough.

Apologies if this is already asked, but could find an answer for it.

Comment: How else would it do its job of installing the library? Installing a library without dependencies isn't installing the library at atll.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. So I might have to think of another way for my library to download its dependencies. Because right now, it hits the limit for downloading because my CI pipeline builds it every time somebody pushes the code.